# shortest route when using waypoints

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i can use waypoints perfectyl.but i can not get shortest directions.i try to use  route alternatives but it doesn't work. i need some thing like this :     http://i58.tinypic.com/2vjbt6d.jpg

is there any way ?

my codes

```
function codeAddress(adres) {
        var address = adres;  
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            }
        });

    }

    function calcRoute() {
        var grid = document.getElementById('GridView1');
        var start = document.getElementById('DropDownList_ilce').value + "," + document.getElementById('DropDownList_il').value;
        var end = document.getElementById('GridView1').rows[grid.rows.length - 1].cells[4].innerHTML + "," + document.getElementById('GridView1').rows[grid.rows.length - 1].cells[3].innerHTML;

        var waypts = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < grid.rows.length - 2; i++) {
            waypts.push({
                location: document.getElementById('GridView1').rows[i+1].cells[4].innerHTML + "," + document.getElementById('GridView1').rows[i+1].cells[3].innerHTML,
                stopover: true
            });
        }


        var request = {
            origin: start,
            destination: end,
            waypoints: waypts,
            optimizeWaypoints: true,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
        });
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What route alternatives are you unable to get? Examples?

Comment: i cant get shortest route and i need shortest route.this code gives me just one route and its the longest route.

Comment: What are the **origin** and **destination** of your directions request?

Comment: Origin : cerkeş,çankırı.  Destination:diyarbakır

Comment: You are pushing waypoints to your route request. Have you tried without the waypoints?

Comment: Yes i tried but result is same. But on real google maps with this origin and destination it gives short distance 970km. But in my program this codes gives long distance 1170 km

Comment: Mmmh... I see the issue. Let me check what can be done. There seems to be no option to return the shortest route by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, the API seems to give no option parameter to return the shortest route by default.

The key here is to use `provideRouteAlternatives: true` as DirectionsRequest property:

```
var request = {
    origin: 'cerkeş,çankırı',
    destination: 'diyarbakır',
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
    provideRouteAlternatives: true
};
```

For the given origin and destination, this will return 2 separate routes. One of 970km and one of 1137 km.

Then you will have to calculate which route is the shortest. You could do something like that:

```
directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {

    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

        var distance = null;
        var routeIndex = 0;

        // Loop through the routes to find the shortest one
        for (var i=0; i<response['routes'].length; i++) {

            var routeDistance = response['routes'][i].legs[0].distance.value;

            if (distance === null) {

                distance = routeDistance;
                routeIndex = i;
            }

            if (routeDistance < distance) {

                distance = routeDistance;
                routeIndex = i;
            }
        }

        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

        // Set route index
        directionsDisplay.setOptions({ 
            routeIndex: routeIndex
        });
    }
});
```

Note that when you have multiple routes, the key is to set the route index of the one you want to show.

```
// Set route index
directionsDisplay.setOptions({
    routeIndex: routeIndex
});
```

This example doesn't use waypoints. I believe that if you use waypoints, you will end up with multiple `DirectionsLeg` legs. In which case, you will have to do a bit more calculation to add each leg distance to find the total route distance.

Hope this helps!